# Angular 5 Internationalization html direction attribute?

Tags: angular, internationalization, direction

How can we change html `dir` attribute in angular 5 internationalization base on selected culture?
I mean, change it to `ltr` or `rtl` automatically!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Use `ltr`. Html Code is:

```
  <div i18n-dir dir="ltr">
         <!-- The rest of the content --> 
 </div>
```